# Getting info from JSON in VB.NET using Json.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I need to process this JSON:

```
{
"companies": [
    {
        "companyId": "S86jhs89F",
        "companyName": "LoremIpsum"
    }
],
"response_metadata": {
    "next_cursor": 659,
    "next_link": "somedata"
} }
```

How can I get companyId, companyName, next_cursor and next_link using VB.NET?

**Update...**

I found this...

```
Dim json As String = "{ ... textJSON ... }"
Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList
Dim output As String = ""
For Each grupo As JProperty In data
    grupo.CreateReader()
    Select Case grupo.Name
        Case "companies"
            For Each item As JObject In grupo.Values
                output += vbCrLf + " -- " + item("companyId").ToString
                output += vbCrLf + " -- " + item("companyName").ToString
            Next
        Case "response_metadata"
            Dim dato As JObject = grupo.Value
            output += vbCrLf + " -- " + dato("next_cursor").ToString
    End Select
Next
```

I don´t know if this is the optimal way, but it is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has a cool feature called Paste JSON as Classes that can be found under Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes. If you were to do this, then you would get something that looks like the following:

```vb
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property companies() As Company
    Public Property response_metadata As Response_Metadata
End Class

Public Class Response_Metadata
    Public Property next_cursor As Integer
    Public Property next_link As String
End Class

Public Class Company
    Public Property companyId As String
    Public Property companyName As String
End Class
```

You can use decorators to make the property names conform to a more .NET style if you wanted:

```vb
Public Class Rootobject
    <JsonProperty("companies")>
    Public Property Companies As IEnumerable(Of Company)

    <JsonProperty("response_metadata")>
    Public Property ResponseMetadata As Response_Metadata
End Class

Public Class Response_Metadata

    <JsonProperty("next_cursor")>
    Public Property NextCursor As Integer

    <JsonProperty("next_link")>
    Public Property NextLink As String
End Class

Public Class Company

    <JsonProperty("companyId")>
    Public Property CompanyId As String


    <JsonProperty("companyName")>
    Public Property CompanyName As String
End Class
```

Now you would use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to convert the JSON literal to your root object. After that, it's just a matter of getting the required properties:

```vb
Dim conversion = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(literal)
Dim companyId = conversion.Companies.First().CompanyId
Dim companyName = conversion.Companies.First().CompanyName
' etc.
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GiGKwI